# Is this the right input for a Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to build an algoritm to predict if a text is misogynistic or not. The data I am using is from a .csv file and has the following labels: id,text,label (0 not misogynistic, 1 is misogynistic). The model is working because I tested on a premade dataset with a premade dictionary so the problem must be the way I process my data. I tried to make my own dictionary using the bag of words method and then shaping my data so it can fit the model but it stops at the first epoch. The full code is the following:

```
import random
import sklearn
import tensorflow as td
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import nltk
from collections import Counter

def get_corpus_vocabulary(corpus):
    counter = Counter()
    for text in corpus:
        tokens=tokenize(text)
        counter.update(tokens)
    return counter

def tokenize(text):
    return nltk.WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(text)

def get_representation(vocabulary, how_many):
    most_comm = vocabulary.most_common(how_many)
    wd2idx = {}
    idx2wd = {}

    for position,word in enumerate(most_comm):
        word=words[0] 
        wd2idx[word] = position
        idx2wd[position] = word
    return wd2idx, idx2wd

def shape_data(data):
    #encoded_data = np.array()
    data_clean = data.copy()
    for line in range(len(data)):
        transtable = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
        data_clean[line] = data[line].translate(transtable).strip().split(" ")
        encoded_line = encode(data_clean[line])
        encoded_line = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences([encoded_line], value=word_index["<PAD>"], padding="post", maxlen=35)
        if line == 0:
            encoded_data = np.array(encoded_line)
        else:
            encoded_data = np.append(encoded_data, encoded_line, axis = 0)
    return encoded_data

def encode(word_list):
    encoded = [1] 
    for word in word_list:
        if word in word_index:
            encoded.append(word_index[word])
        else:
            encoded.append(2)
    return encoded

train_data=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
corpus=train_data['text']
train_labels = train_data['label'].values

all_words=get_corpus_vocabulary(corpus)
word_index, index_word = get_representation(all_words,100000)

#v+3 for 1,2,3; 0 never had a key
word_index = {k:(v+3) for k,v in word_index.items()} #dictionary
word_index["<PAD>"] = 0
word_index["<START>"] = 1
word_index["<UNK>"] = 2
word_index["<UNUSED>"] = 3

encoded_train_data = shape_data(corpus)

#model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(100, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

x_val = encoded_train_data[:1000]
x_train = encoded_train_data[1000:]

y_val = train_labels[:1000]
y_train = train_labels[1000:]

fitModel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=1)
results = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
print(results)
```

I would also like to mention that x_train, y_train, x_val and y_val are all numpy ndarrays.

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/programare/python/ProiectML/neuronalNetwork.py", line 99, in <module>
    fitModel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=40, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=1)
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 840, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  indices[448,1] = 453 is not in [0, 100)
     [[node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup (defined at /programare/python/ProiectML/neuronalNetwork.py:99) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_850]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup:
 sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup/575 (defined at \Users\User\.conda\envs\tensor\lib\contextlib.py:112)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: Please format your error messages as code, not as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(len(word_index), 16))
```